# Searching and Deleting stuff from Observable Collections in C#?

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm having trouble here. I have an observable collection, and I want to delete some of the stuff in it if it meets a certain criteria.

Here's the code:

```
foreach (Record record in SwearJarController.Records)
        {
            if (record.Word == "Hi")
            {


                SwearJarController.Records.Remove(record);
                Datastore.DB.Records.DeleteOnSubmit(record);


            }
        }
```

Records is the name of the collections, and record is the class. Apparently, it gets confused at the 'foreach' part.

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: "it gets confused at the 'foreach' part." - what exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot modify a collection that you are enumerating. You must do a `ToArray()` or `ToList()` on your foreach:

```
foreach (Record record in SwearJarController.Records.ToArray())
{
    if (record.Word == "Hi")
    {
            SwearJarController.Records.Remove(record);
            Datastore.DB.Records.DeleteOnSubmit(record);
    }
}
```

---

Cleaned up version:

```
foreach (Record record in SwearJarController.Records
                          .Where(x => String.Equals(x.Word, "Hi")
                          .ToArray())
{
    SwearJarController.Records.Remove(record);
    Datastore.DB.Records.DeleteOnSubmit(record);
}
```

Note: You should really use `String.Equals(...)` and use a `StringComparison` enumeration as well. I'm not sure if your comparison was meant to be case sensitive and/or ordinal/currentculture/invariantculture.

Comment: It's worth noting that your standard for-loop is more efficient because you can remove the records as you loop vs. looping first, then seeking each record for deletion. Though, for most cases the performance is negligible and this is easier to read. See Bambu's answer for a for-loop version if you need the performance gain. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the collection while you are working on it. You can run a for loop with the count going from Records.Count down to 0 and remove that way. That should work

Example:

```
for(int x = SwearJarController.Records.Count - 1 ; x >= 0; x--)
{
    Record record = SwearJarController.Records[x];
    if(record.Word == "Hi")
    {
        SwearJarController.Records.Remove(record);
        Datastore.DB.Records.DeleteOnSubmit(record);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, you can't modify a collection while you are iterating thru it.

Your best bet for deleting your records cleanly is to do the following:

```
foreach (var record in SwearJarController.Records
    .Where(r => r.Word == "Hi")
    .ToArray())
{
    SwearJarController.Records.Remove(record);
    Datastore.DB.Records.DeleteOnSubmit(record);
}
```

This filters and snapshots your `SwearJarController.Records` collection before deleting.

Doing the filter first limits the possibility of a large array being created.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a try at this soon. A little late to get into Visual Studio at the moment. Time for me to hit the hay.